# DatePicker in MAUI appears full screen and aligned to the left-top corner in Android

Tags: xamarin, cross-platform, maui, android-datepicker, maui-android

[image: DatePicker in the left top corner]

Hello. I am developing an MAUI app in which I have to use a customized date picker without borders.

However, it appears in the corner of the screen and not in the middle as it should. I am using .Net 7 right now.

Here's a sample of my code.

```
public class BorderLessDatePicker : DatePicker
{

        public static readonly BindableProperty TextAlignmentProperty = BindableProperty.Create("TextAlignment", typeof(PickerTextAlignment), typeof(BorderLessDatePicker), (PickerTextAlignment)0, BindingMode.TwoWay);
        public PickerTextAlignment TextAlignment
        {
            get { return (PickerTextAlignment)GetValue(TextAlignmentProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextAlignmentProperty, value); }
        }

        public enum PickerTextAlignment
        {
            Center,
            Right,
            Left
        }
}
```

```
public class BorderLessDatePickerMapper 
{

        private static BorderLessDatePicker viewCast;

        public static void Map(IDatePickerHandler handler, IDatePicker view)
        {

            if (view is BorderLessDatePicker)
            {

                viewCast = (BorderLessDatePicker)view;

                // Remove borders
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                gd.SetStroke(0, Android.Graphics.Color.LightGray);
                handler.PlatformView.SetBackground(gd);
                
                handler.PlatformView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

                // TextAlignment for date value
                if (viewCast.TextAlignment == BorderLessDatePicker.PickerTextAlignment.Right)
                    handler.PlatformView.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Right;
                else if (viewCast.TextAlignment == BorderLessDatePicker.PickerTextAlignment.Center)
                    handler.PlatformView.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Center;
                else if (viewCast.TextAlignment == BorderLessDatePicker.PickerTextAlignment.Left)
                    handler.PlatformView.Gravity = Android.Views.GravityFlags.Left;
            }
        }


       
}
```

```
 <controls:BorderLessDatePicker 
       Format="MM/dd/yyyy"
       TextAlignment="Right"
       MaximumDate="9/18/2023"
       VerticalOptions="Center"
       HorizontalOptions="Fill">
 </controls:BorderLessDatePicker>
```

And in MAUIProgram.cs, the following

```
 Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.DatePickerHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("DatePickerCustomization", (handler, view) =>
{
            if (view is BorderLessDatePicker)
            {
                BorderLessDatePickerMapper.Map(handler, view);
            }
});
```

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Based on your code, I created a demo and deployed it to my android emulator(pixel5-API 33), the result was that if I clicked the date on my screen, a DataPicker was popped up. And the DatePicker is in the center of the screen.

Comment: On what device did you test it? And what is the specific version?

Comment: Hi Jessie, thanks for your help. I tested it on android emulator (pixel5- API 30). My min SDK is 23 and my target is 33.

Comment: Based on your code, I tested the same effect as a regular `DatePicker`.  Could you please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  here?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, Jessie! Much appreciated. I found the root cause of this issue and it turned out to be entirely different than what I had thought. I have customized the datepicker and used the following to apply the style.
<item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

Now if you are extending "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight" you must use the following

<item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>

This resolved the issue. But thanks a ton for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of this issue and it turned out to be something way different than what I had thought.

I have a customized Datepicker here and the style goes like this.

```
 <style name="MainTheme.PATH.Base" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
 </style>
```

Now if you are extending a Material theme, you should use the following to customize it.

```
<item name="materialCalendarTheme">@style/AppCompatDialogStyle</item>
```

Also instead of

```
 <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
 </style>
```

You are supposed to use

```
  <style name="AppCompatDialogStyle" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.MaterialCalendar">
  </style>
```

Thanks.